# Necesisto un ejemplo de archivo XML que funcione en "XML source" de SSIS con la opción "Use inline schema"

Tags: xml, ssis

Necesito leer un archivo XML desde el componente XML Source Editor del SSIS, con la opción de "Use inline schema" activada.

Hice pruebas con este formato pero no me devuelve columnas:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:x="urn:book"> 
<!-- START OF SCHEMA -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:book">
 <xsd:element name="book">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:float"/>
      <xsd:element name="publish_date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<!-- END OF SCHEMA -->
   <x:book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
      XML.</description>
   </x:book>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede crear una con T-SQL.  Busque "for XML Path()".  For ejemplo:

```
SELECT [GroupId]
      ,[GroupCode]
      ,[Name]
FROM [FCRDashBoard].[dbo].[Group]
for xml path('groups'), root
```

Crea...

```
<root>
  <groups>
    <GroupId>1</GroupId>
    <NaicGroupCode>3678</NaicGroupCode>
    <Name>Sudamericano Independiente Grp</Name>
  </groups>
  <groups>
    <GroupId>5</GroupId>
    <NaicGroupCode>429</NaicGroupCode>
    <Name>GUARDA VIDA GRP</Name>
  </groups>
</root>
```